# Upgrading Cisco ISE to 1.2

Tags: cisco, cisco-ise

I have a standalone ISE node, which is being stubborn about an upgrade...

The [docs](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/ise/1-2/upgrade_guide/b_ise_upgrade_guide/b_ise_upgrade_guide_chapter_01.html#ID203) say this should work, but I'm getting an error...

```
ISE-01/admin# application upgrade ise-upgradebundle-1.1.x-to-1.2.0.899.i386.tar.gz disk

Save the current ADE-OS running configuration? (yes/no) [yes] ? yes
Generating configuration...
Saved the ADE-OS running configuration to startup successfully
Initiating Application Upgrade...

% Repository not found
ISE-01/admin#
```

### Question

What CLI do I need to use to successfully upgrade ISE 1.1?

A directory listing for `disk:` and show version follows...

```
ISE-01/admin# dir disk:/

Directory of disk:/
 3976667523 May 15 2014 09:40:44  ise-upgradebundle-1.1.x-to-1.2.0.899.i386.tar.gz
      16384 Jun 04 2013 09:50:51  lost+found/

           Usage for disk: filesystem
                 4153323520 bytes total used
                10294484992 bytes free
                15234142208 bytes available
ISE-01/admin#
ISE-01/admin# sh ver

Cisco Application Deployment Engine OS Release: 2.0
ADE-OS Build Version: 2.0.4.018
ADE-OS System Architecture: i386

Copyright (c) 2005-2011 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
All rights reserved.
Hostname: ISE-01


Version information of installed applications
---------------------------------------------

Cisco Identity Services Engine
---------------------------------------------
Version      : 1.1.1.268
Build Date   : Mon Jun 25 00:49:23 2012
Install Date : Tue Apr 29 10:49:41 2014

ISE-01/admin#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves the problem...

```
ISE-01/admin# conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
ISE-01/admin(config)#
ISE-01/admin(config)# repository LOCAL
ISE-01/admin(config-Repository)# url disk:/
ISE-01/admin(config-Repository)# end
ISE-01/admin# end
```

Now the upgrade works...

```
ISE-01/admin#  application upgrade ise-upgradebundle-1.1.x-to-1.2.0.899.i386.tar.gz LOCAL
Save the current ADE-OS running configuration? (yes/no) [yes] ?
Generating configuration...
Saved the ADE-OS running configuration to startup successfully
Initiating Application Upgrade...
% Warning: Do not use Ctrl-C or close this terminal window until upgrade completes.
STEP 1: Stopping ISE application...
```